# How to get changes between 2 arrays of objects? [ lodash/ JS]

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have a table already populated with dataset from API. For demo, let just say I have 2 already added row on the table which I fetched from API. Now, I edited the second row also added another row. So what I want to achieve is that I want to get a new array of objects which have the the row I just edited along with the row I just added.

Following are the 2 arrays with dummy dataset I have.

**First Array:**

```
[
  { id: '38sj3-23', user: { id: 21323 }, count: { start: 12, end: 24 }, point: 56 },
  { id: '38sj3-23', user: { id: 21323 }, count: { start: 8, end: 36 }, point: 49 },
]
```

**Second Array:**

```
[
  { id: '38sj3-23', user: { id: 21323 }, count: { start: 12, end: 24 }, point: 56 },
  { id: '38sj3-23', user: { id: 21323 }, count: { start: 36, end: 97 }, point: 15 },
  { id: null, count: { start: 123, end: 2135 }, point: 323 },
]
```

Notice that I edited the 2nd row values in the `Second Array`. The third row in the 2nd array doesn't have user id because the `userId` will returned from server after posting it

**Expected Output:**

```
[
  { id: '38sj3-23', user: { id: 21323 }, count: { start: 36, end: 97 }, point: 15 },
  { id: null, count: { start: 123, end: 2135 }, point: 323 },
]
```

I tried `lodash` `_.differencWith` / `_.intersectWith` but the output using that was like this below

```
[
  { id: null, count: { start: 123, end: 2135 }, point: 323 },
]
```

Only returned the newly added row on the table but ignored that I changed the values on the 2nd row as well.

**NOTE**: The table have only 3 columns where all of them are editable. `coun: { start, end}` and `point`

Comment: did you tried: `_.differenceWith(x, y, _.isEqual)`? where x,y are 2 arrays

Comment: @Mani Yes `_.differenceWith(second, first, _.isEqual)`. I tried it like this.

Comment: I am getting expected output from that function, can you check solution and run from that solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `_.differenceWith`(https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#differenceWith)

```js
const first=[
  { id: '38sj3-23', user: { id: 21323 }, count: { start: 12, end: 24 }, point: 56 },
  { id: '38sj3-23', user: { id: 21323 }, count: { start: 8, end: 36 }, point: 49 },
]

const second=[
  { id: '38sj3-23', user: { id: 21323 }, count: { start: 12, end: 24 }, point: 56 },
  { id: '38sj3-23', user: { id: 21323 }, count: { start: 36, end: 97 }, point: 15 },
  { id: null, count: { start: 123, end: 2135 }, point: 323 },
]

let result=_.differenceWith(second, first, _.isEqual)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

`_.differenceWith`:

This method is like `_.difference` except that it accepts comparator which is invoked to compare elements of array to values. The order and references of result values are determined by the first array. The comparator is invoked with two arguments: `(arrVal, othVal)`.

Comment: This seems to work but in my project It doesn't.  Could you please check the code snippet I added in the below link. It seems to only return the newly added row

https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#iu37oyqaa7mbci0d8zipiv

Comment: https://ibb.co/6JMpzDh  <--- check this image.. this is the output I am getting

Comment: Sorry. there might have been a mistake by me... Please let me check again properly.. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Okay, feel free to share if you stuck at any point

Comment: I found the issue. I was doing the lodash operation correctly but the problem was my `firstArray` was getting updated when I am changing the `secondArray` because of the same reference. Now I used the `_.cloneDeep` of lodash then compared and its working now...

Thank you for you time and effort, I was able realize the mistake..

Answer (score 0):

```js
const a = [
  { id: '38sj3-23', user: { id: 21323 }, count: { start: 12, end: 24 }, point: 56 },
  { id: '38sj3-23', user: { id: 21323 }, count: { start: 8, end: 36 }, point: 49 },
]

const b = [
  { id: '38sj3-23', user: { id: 21323 }, count: { start: 12, end: 24 }, point: 56 },
  { id: '38sj3-23', user: { id: 21323 }, count: { start: 36, end: 97 }, point: 15 },
  { id: null, count: { start: 123, end: 2135 }, point: 323 },
];

result = _.differenceWith(b, a, _.isEqual)
console.log(result); // your excpected result.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```